# Excel export add apostrophy with number started with 0

Tags: php, excel, csv, apostrophe

I'm trying to export data using below code and eveything working fine except number started with 0

```
header( 'Content-type: application/xls' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export-"'.$filename.'".xls' );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

I've tried to concat ' using below query and it showng full number with 0 but covert it to string and I need it number and apostrophy need to display on cell click in excel sheet.

```
SELECT CONCAT('\'', account_number) FROM orderinfo
```

Is there any way to add this, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "numbers" don't start with a zero

Comment: Is there any way to add same as excel sheet, As if in excel sheet we will add number like '00015555 but will display 00015555 and ' will display if we will click on cell